# Delete cookie that begins with a specific string in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies

I have a rails app that includes the ability for users to get multiple quotes. I am storing each quote in a cookie like this:

```
   if !results.nil?
      cookies["quote_#{SecureRandom.uuid}"]
    end
```

As the user creates multiple quotes I will be pulling the cookies out to display o the screen. I want the user to be able to delete or all their quotes by clicking a button.

How can I use some sort of wildcard to delete all the cookies that start with quote_? So something like...

```
def clear_cookies
    cookies.delete "quote_*"
    redirect_to compare_path
  end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can iterate on your cookies and use `delete`method only on desired cookies :

```
cookies.each { |key, _| cookies.delete(key) if key.start_with?("quote_") }
```

Comment: Nice one! I never knew there is a method called `start_with?` until now.